# A question about linear orderings and their initial segments

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Assume $\langle X,< \rangle$ is a linear order. Let $\kappa$ be some cardinal.
For $x\in X$, denote --

$Pred(x) = \{ a\in X \colon a<x \}$

Assume that --

$\forall x\in X , |Pred(x)|<\kappa$.

Is it true that $|X|\leq \kappa$ ?

I know the following:

1. If $\langle X,< \rangle$ is a well order, then the answer is YES, (By comparing $\langle X, < \rangle $ and $\langle \kappa,\in \rangle$ as well orders: they are either isomorphic, or one of them is isomorfic to the other's initial segment. From this $|X|\leq \kappa$ follows easily).
2. Under GCH, the answer is YES as well (In the proof I assumed the axiom of choice - i've used [Konig's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_(set_theory)) ).

It's seems unlikely for me that $\mathbb R$ may be well ordered, in a way that any initial segment is countable (Where CH fails. If it holds then it's obviously true) - But I couldn't refute it. Is there something i'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\lambda$ be the cofinality of the linear order on $X$, and let $\langle x_\xi:\xi<\lambda\rangle$ be a strictly increasing cofinal sequence in $X$. Clearly $|X|\le\lambda\cdot\sup_{\xi<\lambda}|\operatorname{Pred}(x_\xi)|\le\lambda\cdot\kappa$. And clearly $\lambda\le\kappa$, as otherwise $x_\kappa$ has too many predecessors. Thus, $|X|\le\kappa$.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's much simpler than I thought

Comment: @user333618: You’re very welcome.